# Navigation menu with 2 links in drop-down only opens the menu. It is not directed link?

Tags: navigation, menu, drop-down-list

I have a navigation where one of the items has 2 sub-links. Clicking on property it would open the menu only. I know many people feel the parent should direct you to a page, but in this scenario I don't think it is necessary because there is no overview property page.

The other option is: since both of these links are sub navs on both pages, I could remove the menu and have the Property label take you to Available page by default (which most users come for).
[image: navigation menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest navigation that is intuitive to users is always the best approach. So if both links are tabs on both pages (I'm understanding that as all the Available and Featured Closing content is available for users to navigate between on both pages), you should definitely simplify this for users and have the Property label take you to Available page by default.

However, that's only if having user friendly navigation is your main goal. I'm assuming from your menu item titles that your working on some kind of real estate site which is a very competitive industry. Best practices SEO wise would have Available and Featured Closing as separate pages with no tabs or duplicated content between them. You would also want Property to be a page with lots of keywords and CTA links to Available and Closings.

Comment: sorry I should of been more detailed. They have tabs but go to separate pages. More like a sub nav. It works right now like you mentioned Property only no menu for those reasons. Good to be reminded. Thank you